# How to play random Mp3 files in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

hi everyone i'm currently working on a project and i'm stuck with this problem. how can i randomly play Mp3 from one folder using Pygame? here is my code.

```py
path = "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/sample_songs/"
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(path)
mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to get a list of all the files which ends with `'.mp3'` in the directory (`os.listdir`, see [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)):

```py
import os

path = "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/sample_songs/"
all_mp3 = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.mp3')]
```

then select a random file from the list (`random.choice`, see [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)):

```py
import random

randomfile = random.choice(all_mp3)
```

Play the random file:

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(randomfile)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import os
import random
import pygame

directory = 'music'
play_list = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.mp3')]
print(play_list)
current_list = []

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 100))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window_center = window.get_rect().center
title_surf = None

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        if not current_list:
           current_list = play_list[:]
           random.shuffle(current_list)
        current_song = current_list.pop(0)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(directory, current_song))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        title_surf = font.render(current_song, True, (255, 255, 0))

    window.fill(0)
    if title_surf:
        window.blit(title_surf, title_surf.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: i got an error "NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid". On all_mp3 part

Comment: @ZionMiguel So "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/sample_songs/" is not a directory

Comment: nevermind. i got the path wrong. some typo haha. Anyway thank you so much

Comment: i do have a off topic question thou. is it possible to use a 2 mic in speech recogniton in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get a list of all files in a folder. Then use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose a random file.

If all files in the directory are MP3 files, you could use something like this:

```py
import os
import random

path = "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/sample_songs/"
file = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(file)
mixer.music.play()
```